# Loading div using jQuery.get()

Tags: php, jquery, get

I have this code

```
$.get('test.php', function(data){

  $(data).appendTo('#content');

});
```

i need to load a specific div from test.php like .load() ,and i can't use .load() because i need to use .appendTo(), how to do this by jQuery.get()

Comment: And what's wrong with `$('#content').load('test.php #someElement');`

Comment: @adeneo how to use .appendTo() with your line code??

Comment: @Jim - the point being, why do **you have to** use `appendTo()` ???

Comment: @adeneo i need to add the new content to a specific div content not replace it.

Comment: @magedali you mean like load more situation add the new content after the current content through ajax?

Comment: You'd solve that with : `$('<span />').appendTo('#content').load('test.php #someElement');` I really don't see why you **have to** use `appendTo()`, there are at least half a dusin other jQuery methods that work as well, I was just wondering why it had to be that specific method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean you just need to parse the returned HTML?  You should be able to just use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
$.get('test.php', function(data){
  var yourDiv = $(data).find('.yourDiv');// Use your selector here
  yourDiv.appendTo('#content');
});
```

Comment: @magedali No problem, glad to have helped.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$.get('test.php', function(data){

  var div = $(data).find('#divid');
$('#content').append(div);

});
```